# radiobuttonlist value with regex error

Tags: regex, radiobuttonlist

I'm trying to remove any html tags, mainly  from the value piece of a radiobuttonlist item.  Without the regex, it works, but causes other errors.  Here's what I have, but the error it gives is:  Object reference not set to an instance of an object. `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`  `rad.DataValueField = myStr.stripHTML(ds.Tables("session_name").ToString)`  Any advice appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
  Dim rad As RadioButtonList = New RadioButtonList()
  rad.ID = "rad" + i.ToString()
  rad.DataSource = ds.Tables("conSessions")
  rad.DataTextField = ds.Tables("conSessions").Columns("session_name").ToString
  rad.DataValueField = myStr.stripHTML(ds.Tables("session_name").ToString)
  rad.DataBind()
  rad.DataBind()
  rad.SelectedIndex = 0
  phConcurrent.Controls.Add(rad)

Public Function stripHTML(ByVal e As String) As String
    If (e = String.Empty) Or (IsDBNull(e) = True) Then
       Return ""
    Else
       Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(e, "<[^>]*>", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Is myStr set to an instance of your stripper class?  Consider making stringHTML static if you don't need separate implementations.

Comment: Also, a stacktrace would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is not in regex. Possibly you're trying to get wrong table here:

```
ds.Tables("session_name").ToString
```

Are you sure that you need table with this name and not with name "conSessions" ?

Comment: I'm getting the data, but while it displays fine as text, it gives an error as the value for the radiobuttonlist. I've tried the replace function but cannot get it to work. I've also tried a regexp and cannot get it to work. What I get in the control is: value="TestZ Session 3 &lt;i>Italics&lt;/i>" checked="checked" but the actual data is correct. I just need to remove all html tags within the code on the page so that the text display will still reflect them.